# Resize Image Maps on Fluid Carousel Images

Tags: javascript, html, css, carousel, imagemap

- I have a carousel with fluid images and image maps.
- With [David Bradshaw's image-map-resizer code](https://github.com/davidjbradshaw/image-map-resizer/blob/master/README.md), the 1st slide's image map always nicely adjusts to the screen size.
- Other slides' image maps only resize if I first have the browser screen maximized & then make the screen smaller. If I load the page on a non-maximized browser screen, the image maps (besides the 1st one) don't adjust.

**What can I tweak so that the images maps for all slides adjust based on screen size?**

**[See CodePen](https://codepen.io/ugliestutopian/pen/ExEQPog)**  **<---**

```js
/*! Image Map Resizer (imageMapResizer.min.js ) - v1.0.10 - 2019-04-10
 *  Desc: Resize HTML imageMap to scaled image.
 *  Copyright: (c) 2019 David J. Bradshaw - dave@bradshaw.net
 *  License: MIT
 */
! function() {
  "use strict";

  function r() {
    function e() {
      var r = {
          width: u.width / u.naturalWidth,
          height: u.height / u.naturalHeight
        },
        a = {
          width: parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(u, null).getPropertyValue("padding-left"), 10),
          height: parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(u, null).getPropertyValue("padding-top"), 10)
        };
      i.forEach(function(e, t) {
        var n = 0;
        o[t].coords = e.split(",").map(function(e) {
          var t = 1 == (n = 1 - n) ? "width" : "height";
          return a[t] + Math.floor(Number(e) * r[t])
        }).join(",")
      })
    }

    function t(e) {
      return e.coords.replace(/ *, */g, ",").replace(/ +/g, ",")
    }

    function n() {
      clearTimeout(d), d = setTimeout(e, 250)
    }

    function r(e) {
      return document.querySelector('img[usemap="' + e + '"]')
    }
    var a = this,
      o = null,
      i = null,
      u = null,
      d = null;
    "function" != typeof a._resize ? (o = a.getElementsByTagName("area"),
      i = Array.prototype.map.call(o, t),
      u = r("#" + a.name) || r(a.name),
      a._resize = e,
      u.addEventListener("load", e, !1),
      window.addEventListener("focus", e, !1),
      window.addEventListener("resize", n, !1),
      window.addEventListener("readystatechange", e, !1),
      document.addEventListener("fullscreenchange", e, !1),
      u.width === u.naturalWidth && u.height === u.naturalHeight || e()) : a._resize()
  }

  function e() {
    function t(e) {
      e && (! function(e) {
        if (!e.tagName) throw new TypeError("Object is not a valid DOM element");
        if ("MAP" !== e.tagName.toUpperCase()) throw new TypeError("Expected <MAP> tag, found <" + e.tagName + ">.")
      }(e), r.call(e), n.push(e))
    }
    var n;
    return function(e) {
      switch (n = [], typeof e) {
        case "undefined":
        case "string":
          Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll(e || "map"), t);
          break;
        case "object":
          t(e);
          break;
        default:
          throw new TypeError("Unexpected data type (" + typeof e + ").")
      }
      return n
    }
  }
  "function" == typeof define && define.amd ? define([], e) : "object" == typeof module && "object" == typeof module.exports ? module.exports = e() : window
    .imageMapResize = e(), "jQuery" in window && (window.jQuery.fn.imageMapResize = function() {
      return this.filter("map").each(r).end()
    })
}();
//# sourceMappingURL=imageMapResizer.map
```

**[See CodePen](https://codepen.io/ugliestutopian/pen/ExEQPog)** **<---**